# How to supply a text file with newlines as input to git push options

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to set a GitLab merge request from the command line, using the `-o merge_request.description="my merge request"` option.

However, I wish to supply an entire Markdown file, and if I do this the command complains that newlines are not allowed. I have also tried using sed to replace all newlines with '\n', but these are then taken literally and my merge request is one line containing lots of '\n's.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Does `-o merge_request.description="$(cat pr.md)"` help? (Requires Bash or git-bash)

Comment: Tried this thanks, I get `fatal: push options must not have new line characters`

Comment: Then I'm afraid there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

Although git push options don't allow for newlines, you can replace newlines with `<br>` to get a similar effect.

```
# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/5747944
description="$(sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/<br>/g' description.md)"
git push -o merge_request.description="$description"
```

Comment: This is potentially a solution if we change our MR templates to HTML but doesn't solve the issue for using markdown which is the preference

Comment: @tsvallender this does work for markdown. HTML markup like `<br>` is allowed to be mixed in with markdown. Though, you will find when editing the description, the `<br>` will be present instead of newlines, which may not be ideal for you. Unfortunately, that's simply a limitation of git push options.

Comment: Yes the tags are allowed within the markdown, but as markdown relies on certain characters - such as # - starting a line, these don't work as they are no longer on a new line.

Comment: Gotcha, yeah. That won't work with this solution, either. Tables, etc, also won't work if using usual markup. I don't think there's any solution for that given push options don't allow newlines.